# Puppeteer: How to get the contents of each element of a nodelist?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, headless-browser

I'm trying to achieve something very trivial: Get a list of elements, and then do something with the `innerText` of each element.

```
const tweets = await page.$$('.tweet');
```

From what I can tell, this returns a nodelist, just like the `document.querySelectorAll()` method in the browser.

How do I just loop over it and get what I need? I tried various stuff, like:

```
[...tweets].forEach(tweet => {
  console.log(tweet.innerText)
});
```

Comment: before trying `forEach`, did you tried `for` loop, like `for(var i = 0; i< tweet.length; i++){ console.log(tweet[i].innerText)}`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

#### page.$$():

You can use a combination of [`elementHandle.getProperty()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#elementhandlegetpropertypropertyname) and [`jsHandle.jsonValue()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#jshandlejsonvalue) to obtain the [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) from an [`ElementHandle`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-elementhandle) obtained with [`page.$$()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageselector-1):

```
const tweets = await page.$$('.tweet');

for (let i = 0; i < tweets.length; i++) {
  const tweet = await (await tweets[i].getProperty('innerText')).jsonValue();
  console.log(tweet);
}
```

If you are set on using the [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method, you can wrap the loop in a promise:

```
const tweets = await page.$$('.tweet');

await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  tweets.forEach(async (tweet, i) => {
    tweet = await (await tweet.getProperty('innerText')).jsonValue();
    console.log(tweet);
    if (i === tweets.length - 1) {
      resolve();
    }
  });
});
```

#### page.evaluate():

Alternatively, you can skip using [`page.$$()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageselector-1) entirely, and use [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args):

```
const tweets = await page.evaluate(() => Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('tweet'), e => e.innerText));

tweets.forEach(tweet => {
  console.log(tweet);
});
```

Comment: I really like the last example. I wasn't even aware of the Array.from() method.

Comment: Does exist any possibility to get rid of 'for' loop and use some array transformation to build array of innerText values for sample with `page$$`?

Comment: +1 been using arrays for ages.. never knew about Array.from! so much better than writing Array.prototype.slice.call!

Comment: The page.$$ version just looks awful, I just don't understand the use case for it?

Answer (score 15):

According to puppeteer docs [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.9.0/docs/api.md#pageselector-1), `$$` Does not return a nodelist, instead it returns a Promise of Array of [ElementHandle](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-elementhandle). It's way different then a NodeList.

There are several ways to solve the problem.

## 1. Using built-in function for loops called `page.$$eval`

This method runs `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector))` within the page and passes it as the first argument to `pageFunction`.

So to get innerText is like following,

```
// Find all .tweet, and return innerText for each element, in a array.
const tweets = await page.$$eval('.tweet', element => element.innerText);
```

## 2. Pass the `elementHandle` to the `page.evaluate`

Whatever you get from `await page.$$('.tweet')` is an array of elementHandle. If you console, it will say `JShandle` or `ElementHandle` depending on the type.

Forget the hard explanation, it's easier to demonstrate.

```
// let's just call them tweetHandle 
const tweetHandles = await page.$$('.tweet');

// loop thru all handles
for(const tweethandle of tweetHandles){

   // pass the single handle below
   const singleTweet = await page.evaluate(el => el.innerText, tweethandle)

   // do whatever you want with the data
   console.log(singleTweet) 
}
```

Of course there are multiple ways to solve this problem, Grant Miller also answered few of them in the other answer.

Comment: Yes, i did more or less what u demonstrated in the second example. Boy does Puppeteer seem overly complicated...I truly wonder how come its mechanics are so different to what we're used to in the browser. I mean, isn't it just a "virtual browser"?

Comment: It is a browser, but the thing is, telling a human to use a browser is a lot different than telling a computer. :D I thought I put the simplest example available for your problem. Sigh.

Comment: For `.$$eval`, the second argument callback is not applied to each element, it's applied to all elements. So `page.$$eval('.tweet', elements => elements.map(e => e.innerText))`