# Page selector odd behaviors in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am trying to grab an element from the DOM of the page I am scraping in puppeteer.

After the page is loaded, I call `page.$('.class-name')`. It returns some weird object of the form `{ ClickTale: {} }`.

When I call `document.querySelector('.class-name')` from the chrome console, I get a completely different object that corresponds to the element I am looking for.

My goal is to access the href property of said element in puppeteer. Thanks

Comment: Could you provide the page URL and a minimal script to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 1):

`page.$(selector)` is different than `document.querySelector`,

- You run `querySelector` inside browser but `page.$` on nodeJS.
- `page.$` returns an `ElementHandle` or `null` depending on result.  querySelector returns a Dom element.

You can grab `href` of the said element using [$eval](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args-1). This will do a querySelector and evaluate on the result.

```
page.$eval('.class-name', elem => elem.href)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to puppeteer too and experienced that too Jak.
I would get an [ElementHandle](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.7.0&show=api-class-elementhandle) [JSHandle](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.7.0&show=api-class-jshandle) in the response.
I managed to extract the links using the [getProperty](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.7.0&show=api-elementhandlegetpropertypropertyname) but I could be doing it wrong.
A better explanation of this is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52827121/puppeteer-how-to-get-the-contents-of-each-element-of-a-nodelist)

```
let te_responce = await page[0].$$('div[class="supergrid-bucket"] > a')
  console.log(`Number of entries ${te_responce.length}`)

for (let i = 0; i < te_responce.length; i++) {
  console.log(`link ${await(await te_responce[i].getProperty('href')).jsonValue()}`)
}
```