# In puppeteer, how I get content of nextSibling of element found by innerText?

Tags: puppeteer

I have following html:

```html
<article data-tid="product-detail"> <!-- I page.$eval on this element. -->
  <h1 itemprop="name">Product name</h1> <!-- This I can query by itemprop -->
  
  <h2>Some other topic</h2>
  <p>I don't want this text.</p>

  <h2>Unique topic</h2> <!-- I can find this innerText === "Unique topic". -->
  <p>Text I want real' bad.</p> <!-- I want this innerText. -->

  <h2>Some other topic</h2>
  <p>I don't want this text.</p>
</article>
```

How do I get the "Text I want real' bad." from the page, knowing the "Unique topic"?

I run puppeteer from node script.

---

This is what I have so far:

```js
async function puppeteerProductDataExtractor($product) {
  // This works like charm. 
  const productName = $product.querySelector('[itemprop=name]')?.innerText;

  // Now I have to find the right h2 and get it's next element sibling. 
  const h2 = $product.querySelectorAll('h2');
  
  // 1. If I try to get innerText of all h2, it fails with getProperty function not defined.
  console.log(
    await Promise.all([...h2].map(async $el => await (await element.getProperty('innerText')).jsonValue()))
  );

  // 2. This returns empty array
  console.log([...h2].filter($el => $el.innerText.startsWith('Unique topic')));
  // This prints JSHandle@array - innerText is not a string. 
  console.log([...h2].map($el => $el.innerText));
  // This also prints JSHandle@array which is just insane.
  console.log([...h2].map($el => Object.keys($el)));
  // This fails with "property is not a function" error. 
  console.log([...h2].map(el => el.property('innerText')));
  // So does this. 
  console.log([...h2].map(el => el.getProperty('innerText')));
}

page.on('console', consoleObj => console.log('xxxx', consoleObj.text()));

const product = await page.$eval('article[data-tid=product-detail]', puppeteerProductDataExtractor);
```

The first attempt comes from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52828950/336753

Everything else is just frustrated blind shooting. Must admit I'm very confused. Some of the stuff should work according to docs, but it just fails. Like JSHandle [should have the `property` function](https://pub.dev/documentation/puppeteer/latest/puppeteer/JsHandle-class.html), but it fails, when I call it (not a function).

I didn't even get to the `nextSibling` part.

I tried a lot of code which mostly failed and don't want to pollute the question with it. It feels this should be really simple and I'm just missing something. Hope the original intention is clear.

I'm sure there is a simple solution, but trial-and-failure seems not to be the way to get to it.

---

After more digging, turns out my original intention was correct. The `filter()` didn't work not because innerText would be instance of JSHandle (as it appears), but because uppercase first letter was done by CSS (had to lowercase to unify the string before comparison). Kinda ashamed here... Sorry and thanks @ggorlen for assistance.

```js
/* WE'RE INSIDE $eval FUNCTION */
// This returns JSHandle@array which is just weird...
console.log([...h2].map(el => el.innerText));
// But this returns the joined string correctly. Huh... 
console.log([...h2].map(el => el.innerText).join(';'));
// So this eventually works
console.log([...h2]
  .filter(el => el.textContent.toLowerCase().startsWith('unique topic'))[0]?
  .nextElementSibling.textContent);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling) rather than [`nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling#notes), which can return a whitespace text node:

```js
const text = document
  .querySelector("h2")
  .nextElementSibling
  .textContent
;
console.log(text);
```

```html
<h2>Unique topic</h2>
<p>Text I want real' bad.</p>
```

While you haven't shared your markup, it looks like you might have multiple of these `<h2>`/`<p>` combos and you want to extract the text from each. This might help get you started:

```js
const text = [...document.querySelectorAll("h2")]
  .map(e => e.nextElementSibling.textContent)
;
console.log(text);
```

```html
<h2>Unique topic 1</h2>
<p>Text I want real' bad. 1</p>
<h2>Unique topic 2</h2>
<p>Text I want real' bad. 2</p>
<h2>Unique topic 3</h2>
<p>Text I want real' bad. 3</p>
```

If it's not obvious, the above code must run inside an `$eval`, `$$eval` or `evaluate`. For example, you could use:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

let browser;
(async () => {
  const html = `
    <h2>Unique topic 1</h2>
    <p>Text I want real' bad. 1</p>
    <h2>Unique topic 2</h2>
    <p>Text I want real' bad. 2</p>
    <h2>Unique topic 3</h2>
    <p>Text I want real' bad. 3</p>
  `;
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setContent(html);
  const contents = await page.$$eval(
    "h2",
    els => els.map(e => e.nextElementSibling.textContent)
  ); 
  console.log(contents);
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close())
;
```

Your line

```js
await (await element.getProperty('innerText')).jsonValue()
```

is pure Node Puppeteer, yet you're attempting to run that inside the browser console. That's a common mistake -- elementHandles work only in Puppeteer. The [thread you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52827121/puppeteer-how-to-get-the-contents-of-each-element-of-a-nodelist/52828950#52828950) offers a bottom example that shows the `evaluate` approach, which uses browser-only code.

For debugging browser code (stuff executed in a callback to `evaluate`, `$eval`, `$$eval`, etc), I recommend attaching a listener to the console as shown in [How do print the console output of the page in puppeter as it would appear in the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58089425/how-do-print-the-console-output-of-the-page-in-puppeter-as-it-would-appear-in-th) or run headfully so you can see the error message.

Another tip is to work out your selectors in the browser by hand, then add them to Puppeteer's `evaluate` only after you have them working. `evaluate` is general, so all DOM manipulation you can do with shorthand Puppeteer `page` and elementHandle convenience methods like `.click()`, `.getProperty()`, `.$eval`, `.$x`, etc can be done directly in `evaluate`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do run my code in node. I wasn't aware that someone would run puppeteer in browser, so I didn't specify it. Also that's why I'm confused with `getProperty` not being defined on the JSHandle. Now that I'm thinking about it, it might be the code, that runs in browser emulator instantiated by node, so perhaps that's why the functions are not defined there. 
I do have console attached (that's how I got the outputs), but it's good you mention it for others too. 
I'll do some more trying based on your notes and maybe edit the question to be more clear. Thanks!